# Multiple fields in mysql query with empty values

Tags: mysql

Hello Guys!!
                I want to display data from database into Gridview for which i have designed the web page and gave the end user to enter their custom values...End user query fields may different  on diffrent times...

for example : Suppose,following fields are there..
Date from ,date to ,extension,trunk,destination,cost...

Now As per requirement if user want the data from datefrom to dateto result should come and if they wants result from datefrom to dateto along with extension and extension result should come....

I am in need of single query for this condition ..

Please guys Help me ...
Thanx in advance....

Comment: Kamal karte ho Pandey Ji! Please paste the code and what you have done so far?

Comment: @diEcho i need the query to get the result sir

Comment: @diEcho Arey sir ji code to mere pass hai par query ni hai query miley to pura grid populate ho jayegi

Answer (score 0):

I think you should in your application check with sort of variables your user sent to you and then start to build up your query as bellow.

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE
    1 = 1
    AND datefrom >= 'YYYY-MM-DD' 
    AND dateto <= 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    AND extension = 'value';
```

You should also consider to create index for the columns in this query.